# SOLR range query for fraction numbers no going to work properly

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a field in solr that contains fraction value like 1.2, 0.523, 4.7 etc.
This field is defined like

```
<field name="ratio" type="float" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
```

In order to search for the range from 0.2 to 1, I am using following query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=bag&df=keywords&wt=json&indent=true&group=true&group.field=ratio&fq=ratio:[0.2 TO 1]
```

But Results I obtained contain ratio grater that 1. Where is the problem in query.

Note: I have to group on this field also that why I applied grouping also. Do not worry about it

Comment: Solr sorting is lexicographice not numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The float field type in Solr has some odd behavior when it comes to range queries...

> Field values will sort numerically, but Range Queries (and other
>   features that rely on numeric ranges) will not work as expected:
>   values will be evaluated in unicode String order, not numeric order.

From: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_4/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/FloatField.html

What you want to use is the equivalent [Trie field](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_4/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TrieField.html) which in this case is a Trie float. So your field should be defined as follows...

```
<field name="ratio" type="tfloat" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
```

Make sure to re-index after changing the schema and then try your range queries again.

Answer (score 0):

Range queries don't work as expected on normal primitive fieldTypes such as float, since for these fields, during range queries lucene sorts the documents in lexicographic order rather than numeric order and then applies range on it. Trie fields or sortable fields should do the trick. Also, for solr 5 and later releases, only trie fields have been supported for primitive types.